# implicit definition and tail recursion

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, logic-programming

Probably the most straightforward definition of the list reversal function in a functional language is (using Haskell-like pseudocode)

```
rev [] = []
rev (x:xs) = (rev xs) ++ [x]
```

However, every beginning functional programmer is taught that this implementation is inefficient and that one should instead write

```
rev' [] acc = acc
rev' (x:xs) acc = rev' xs (x:acc)
rev l = rev' l []
```

A bad thing about the efficient version is that the programmer is forced to introduce an auxiliary function and parameter whose meaning is not very clear.  It occurred to me that it might be possible to avoid this if a language permitted implicit definitions roughly like the following:

```
rev [] = []
(rev (x:xs)) ++ m = (rev xs) ++ (x:m)
```

These equations fully determine the behavior of `rev`, so they might be said to constitute an implicit definition of it.  They do not have the defect of introducing the auxiliary function `rev'`.  Yet there is a natural way of evaluating the function that will be efficient.  For instance, here is a plausible reduction sequence:

```
rev [1,2,3]
matches second line with x=1, xs=[2,3], m=[]
reduces to (rev [2,3]) ++ [1]
matches second line with x=2, xs=[3], m=[1]
reduces to (rev [3]) ++ [2,1]
matches second line with x=3, xs=[], m=[2,1]
reduces to (rev []) ++ [3,2,1]
reduces ultimately to [3,2,1]
```

I don't have much of a sense for how widely this kind of thing could be applied, but it does seem to work nicely in this example at least, and it seems to me that it could at least work for some similar cases where one would otherwise have to introduce auxiliary functions for the sake of efficiency.  Can anyone point me to any papers that discuss something like this or languages that support something like this?  It sort of feels like a logic programming thing to me, but I have very little experience with logic programming.

Comment: I'm slightly confused on this implicit definition thing, can you clarify that a bit?

Comment: Feels off-topic. Haskell and GHC should have their own dev mailing-lists, you could try over there.

Comment: The problem I see is that `++` is just a function name, not a constructor, so how the compiler is supposed to know which function to use when an infinite number of them could have built the value in that way? Or are you suggesting a very special-cased thing that should work only on lists?

Comment: You could always define `rev = foldl (flip (:)) []` if you don't like auxilliary functions.

Comment: One problem is that your syntax allows non-deterministic definitions like `don'tKnow xs ++ ys = ys ++ xs`

Comment: It's not that non-determinism is inherently wrong, it's just a small reason for what turns out to be a huge paradigm shift, in my view.

Comment: Also, just a note on the side, tail recursion is not really what Haskell was designed for, as it may be supported, but it kind of conflicts with lazy evaluation.

Comment: @ThreeFx Well, I feel like that's a bit of an oversimplification. In some cases, tail recursion can be less optimal in a lazy language but in other cases (like this one, actually) it can be more efficient. For instance, you can't start to get any results from `reverse` until it has traversed the full list regardless of how it's implemented, so you don't gain anything from a non-tail recursive solution.

Comment: @ThreeFx Conflicts with lazy evaluation? No. "tail calls" are in the perfect position for lazy evaluation to reduce because they are left-most outermost.

Comment: @AndrewC The `foldl` definition is an interesting suggestion.  I can't help thinking my definition is somehow more transparent, but your definition certainly shows that the issue is not just auxiliary function usage.  One thing is that the `foldl` version repeatedly calls `foldl`, but my version doesn't actually call `(++)` except once at the end, and even then only in a trivial way.

Comment: Your version repeatedly calls `rev`, and mine never calls `(++)`. Both build up the list using `(:)` repeatedly. I don't claim any particular transparency for using the `fold` functions, particularly when `flip`ping `(:)`. Fold functions are worth investing time in because more widely applicable than you realise at first, and the more you use them, the clearer they become. Eventually you reach the point where if your function uses up elements from a list in sequence, you reach for a fold function.

Comment: I think my point about non-determinism is much more important than the fact that I can avoid an auxiliary function by using a fold, though. Typically running non-deterministic algorithms is considerably more expensive for efficiency than deterministic ones, and it's not always clear from a definition whether it is deterministic.

Comment: Actually, the `don'tKnow` definition just seems inconsistent since filling in `[]` for `ys` we get that `don'tKnow` is the identity function, but `(++)` is not commutative.  I guess this sort of just proves your point though that introducing this sort of thing opens a can of worms.  I was mostly just curious if someone had opened that can and made it into a meal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Term-rewriting programming languages allow rules to be written like that. Term-rewriting languages combine a set of rewrite rules with a strategy for applying them. Let's try to implement reverse as you suggest in Pure, a fairly simple and accessible term-rewriting system.

Our first attempt will try to reverse a list as follows:

```
rev [] = [];
(rev (x:xs)) + m = (rev xs) + (x:m)
```

We'll try a few sample queries, reversing the empty list `[]`, a singleton list `[1]`, and a list with 4 elements, `[1,2,3,4]`. We expect the outputs to be `[]`, `[1]`, and `[4,3,2,1]` respectively.

```
> rev [];
[]
> rev [1];
rev [1]
> rev [1,2,3,4];
rev [1,2,3,4]
```

Our first rule worked, but the second one was never applied. `Pure` has a built-in rule for concatenating lists together that might be something like:

```
xs     + [] = xs; // Pure's prelude doesn't actually even include this.
[]     + ys = ys;
(x:xs) + ys = x:(xs + ys);
```

But its rewriting strategy isn't exploring what would happen if each of these steps were reversed. To do so, it would need to, for every term `xs`, consider that it might be possible to instead rewrite the term `xs + []` into something other than `xs`! Instead, we will tell the rewriting system that when rewriting with `rev`, it's useful to consider the reversed list with an empty list appended to it.

```
rev [] = [];
(rev (x:xs)) + m = (rev xs) + (x:m);
rev (x:xs) = (rev (x:xs)) + [];
```

This blows the stack for even a single item list. It turns out our third rule keeps getting applied until the stack overflows, without the second rule ever stopping it.

```
> rev [1];
<stdin>, line 2: unhandled exception 'stack_fault' while evaluating 'rev [1]'
```

We will need more control over the evaluation strategy. By introducing a new symbol, `rev2`, we can stop the third rule from matching. These are the same rules as before, except the rule for `rev2` doesn't need to be seen by the rest of the program.

```
rev [] = [];
rev (x:xs) = (rev2 (x:xs)) + [] with
    (rev2 (x:xs)) + m = (rev xs) + (x:m);
end;
```

This works correctly, but doesn't evaluate as far as we'd like.

```
> rev [];
[]
> rev [1];
[]+[1]
> rev [1,2,3,4];
[]+[4]+[3]+[2]+[1]
```

Worse, `+` is left associative, so this still has the nasty `n^2` running time. That's because, by calling `rev` each time inside `rev2`, we are introducing a new `[]` each time, and only prepending to `[]`. `m` is always `[]`. We need to reference `rev2` in `rev2` so that the rule can be applied directly to its own output. When we do, `rev2` will need its own rule for handling empty lists, and we are starting to repeat ourselves in an unpleasant manner.

```
rev [] = [];
rev (x:xs) = (rev2 (x:xs)) + [] with
    rev2 [] = [];
    (rev2 (x:xs)) + m = (rev2 xs) + (x:m);
end;
```

We now get, almost exactly what we want:

```
> rev [];
[]
> rev [1];
[]+[1]
> rev [1,2,3,4];
[]+[4,3,2,1]
```

We can clean up the duplication of the rule for empty lists and the extra `[]` concatenation by having only one rule for the empty list for `rev2`.

```
rev xs = (rev2 xs) + [] with
    (rev2 []    ) + m = m;
    (rev2 (x:xs)) + m = (rev2 xs) + (x:m);
end;
```

This works perfectly:

```
> rev [];
[]
> rev [1];
[1]
> rev [1,2,3,4];
[4,3,2,1]
```

Now, we can go one step further, and clean up our code a bit. Since everything involving rev2 has the pattern `(rev2 a) + b`, and only symbols matter, we can replace everything of that form with a simpler form, `rev2 a b`.

```
rev xs = rev2 xs [] with
    rev2 []     m = m;
    rev2 (x:xs) m = rev2 xs (x:m);
end;
```

Which is exactly the same as the Haskell definition you were trying to avoid in the first place

```
rev xs = rev' xs [] where
    rev' []     m = m
    rev' (x:xs) m = rev' xs (x:m)
```

Comment: Ha ha.  Actually, I think the uncleaned up version does come pretty close to what I wanted.  It is too bad that you cannot directly express the fact that `rev=rev2` (and then maybe avoid introducing `rev2` as a separate entity altogether.  But it is encouraging that you can specify exactly the control we want using the equations I gave!

Answer (score 1):

The `reverse` function in Prolog will indeed have two arguments, one of which is the accumulator. Logic programs on lists will always exhibit this: `append/3` appends something to the end of a list, and the third 'argument' is the resulting list.

But, the *efficient* reverse predicate in Prolog will *also* have three arguments. See [here:](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Prolog/Lists#Reversing_a_list)

```
revappend([], Ys, Ys).
revappend([X|Xs], Ys, Zs) :- revappend(Xs, [X|Ys], Zs).
reverse(Xs,Ys) :- revappend(Xs,[],Ys).
```

This is *very* similar to the same Problem in Haskell — the naïve Prolog version will, in fact, call `append/3`, which is bad — it corresponds to Haskell's `++`.

Your proposal, it seems to me, would just allow syntax for an optional parameter. So a function is actually defined as a binary function, but you want to be able to call it as a unary function with the second argument instantiated to a default value (the empty list.) It seems to me to be very similar to what Python does (say, a function head of `foo(x,y="bar")` allows you to call `foo("moo")`, and `y` would be `bar`.

But it turns out Haskell programmers don't mind the added layer of indirection sometimes. Just use a `where` keyword so you end up with fewer toplevel functions. There is even a sort of emerging convention where subordinate recursive functions are called `go`. Or, as AndrewC wrote, you can also use folds instead.

Answer (score 1):

Functional Logic Programming languages allows you to define functions with equations that pattern-match on the application of other functions. An introductory article is the following:

Sergio Antoy and Michael Hanus. Functional Logic Programming. Communications of the ACM, volume 53, issue 4 (April 2010), pages 74-85.

Here is a relevant extract from that article:

> For instance, it is apparent from the rule defining `last` that this rule is applicable only if the actual argument has a form that matches the result of narrowing `zs++[e]`. Thus, we can reformulate that rule as:
>   `last (zs++[e]) = e`
>   Note that purely functional languages, such as Haskell, do not allow this rule because it is not constructor-based; rather it contains a functional pattern, that is, a pattern with a defined function inside.

The article uses the [Curry](http://www-ps.informatik.uni-kiel.de/currywiki/) programming language.

Comment: Thanks for the reference, I definitely need to investigate functional logic programming more!  From skimming the article, it doesn't look like Curry supports my definition of `rev`, however, at least not with efficient evaluation.  Is that right?